# Pattern matching with minimum length?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Beginner to regular expressions.

```
import re
rx = r"\(.*?\)/DATE"
s = 'THE (HIGH COURT OF HIMACHAL PRADESH)/ORG, (SHIMLA)/PLACE (Criminal\nAppeal No. 235 of 2006)/CASE Judgment Reserved on : (27. 04. 2016)/DATE\nDate of Decision : (June 2, 2016)/DATE")'
print(re.findall(rx, s))

Now the output is 
['(HIGH COURT OF HIMACHAL PRADESH)/ORG, (SHIMLA)/PLACE (Criminal\nAppeal No. 235 of 2006)/CASE', '(27. 04. 2016)/DATE\nDate of Decision : (Criminal\nAppeal No. 235 of 2006)/CASE]
```

I just want the reduce string rather the string that matched from the beginning.

```
What the output I want?
[(Criminal\nAppeal No. 235 of 2006)/CASE,(Criminal\nAppeal No. 235 of 2006)/CASE]
```

https://ideone.com/rSRENU

Comment: I can't seem to be able to recreate the original output. I am getting "['(27. 04. 2016)/DATE', '(June 2, 2016)/DATE']".

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct, perhaps you should check for typos.

An alternate way is to match non-parenthesis characters `[^()]*` instead of any characters `.*`, like in the following regular expression: `\([^()]*\)/DATE`